# How to achieve right to left animation to start the activity

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I am working on one demo application where I want to apply animation whenever app start any `activity`. I wrote below code but this is for to animate the activity from left to right.

left_to_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

right_to_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

I am here starting an `activity` like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
```

I want to achieve an animation right to left. How this can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Update your animation files as follows:

enter.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

exit.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

You'll have your second activity sliding in from right to the left.

For a better understanding on how to play around with the `fromXDelta` and `toXDelta` values for the animations, here is a very basic illustration on the values:
[image: Activity transition values on X axis]

This way you can easily understand why you add `android:fromXDelta="0%"` and `android:toXDelta="-100%"` for your current activity. And this is because you want it to go from 0% to the -100% position.

**[EDIT]**

So if you want to open ActivityB from ActivityA you do the following (let's say you have a button):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class));
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
        }
    });
```

Now, if you want to have the "backwards" animation of the first one, when you leave Activity B, you'll need 2 new animation files and some code in the ActivityB's `onBackPressed` method, like this:

First the animation files:
left_to_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

right_to_left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

And in ActivityB do the following:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
}
```

Also if you have up navigation enabled, you'll have to add the animation in this case as well:

You enable UP navigation like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

And this is how you handle the animation in this case too:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
       //NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
       finish();
       overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
       return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also be aware that even if your code is okay, your phone might have animation turned off. To turn it on, do the following:

1. Open Settings and go to Developer Options
2. Make sure it is enabled (By sliding the toggle button on the top right)
3. Scroll down and under Drawing, tap these options one by one: Windows animation scale, Transition animation scale, and Animator duration scale
4. Select "Animation scale 1x"

Comment: what to write to start the activity & target activity ?

Comment: Absolutely. I'll add that too

Comment: @Mike can we use the built in android.R.anim.slide_in_left and android.R.anim.slide_out_right?

Comment: first two animations can be reused for the back transition, just swap them? @Mike

Comment: @abdu try it :)

Comment: @Mike Can I use this for the activity which has no toolbar and the activity is fullscreen activity. ?

Comment: @Mike it shows a blank black screen in the background. I want the previous activity is visible in the background. How do I achieve that?

Comment: If  OS direction has rtl so what do?

Answer (score 9):

`overridePendingTransition` should be called in the "target" activity. For example: Going from Activity A -> B, you would put the `overridePendingTransition` call in the `onCreate` of Activity B.

Keep in mind, if the user has disabled animation on a system level, you can't force animations to show.

EDIT:

An example would look like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter, R.anim.exit);
}
```

Comment: what to write in target activity to achieve that ?

Comment: please see edit for an example to add to your Activity A and B

Comment: this is the working answer espcially in case of newly introduced result launcher

Answer (score 5):

This is the perfect code for me
Slideinleft

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="800"/>
```

Slideinright

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:duration="800"/>
```

In Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),termcondionactivity.class);
Bundle bndlAnimation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slideinleft, R.anim.slideinright).toBundle();

startActivity(intent, bndlAnimation);
```

Answer (score 3):

To apply activity transition animation on the entire application, we need to follow a few steps.

Step 1. Create four animation resources. **(slide_in_left, slide_in_right, slide_out_left and slide_out_right)**

Resource file: slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Resource file: slide_in_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Resource file: slide_out_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
 </set>
```

Resource file: slide_out_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" />
 </set>
```

Step 2. Create a custom style and use animation resources.

```
<style name="MyCustomActivityAnimation" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">
        @anim/slide_in_right
    </item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">
        @anim/slide_out_left
    </item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">
        @anim/slide_in_left
    </item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">
        @anim/slide_out_right
    </item>
</style>
```

Step 3. Apply the style to the theme of the application.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MyCustomActivityAnimation</item>
</style>
```

Step 4. Apply the theme to your application in Manifest.

```
<application
   ....
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    ....
 </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it's working for me

**To slide from right to left**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true" >
    <translate
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-50%" >
    </translate>
</set>
```

**To slide from left to right**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-50%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" >
</translate>
```