# Android open activity from right to left on Android 6.+

Tags: android

for this problem or ability i found multiple solutions but i don't know why those solutions are not working on my device. after setting some XML animation to have this ability, my activity is still opening from left right and not from right to left:

**right_to_left.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

**exit.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

Comment: Are you calling overridePendingTransition(..)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to achieve right to left animation to start the activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431017/how-to-achieve-right-to-left-animation-to-start-the-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This code works for me check its work for you ,**
**Use below code for open activity.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Example.class);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

**add two xml files in your anim folder.**

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />
</set>
```

**slide_out_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="-100%" />
    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
</set>
```

Comment: dont work correctly sir, and slowing translate by set duration to `1000` dont work

Comment: Oh my God, this problem is on android 6 :| :|, your code work fine on android 5

Comment: Thanks you very much sir

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Keep these two xml in anim folder,

slide_in_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" >
</translate>
```

stay.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p" />
```

And write after startactivity()

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.stay);
```

Comment: yes, you can try it :), I have checked on 4.4.2,  5.1.1 and 6.0