# How to create bundle in android with both extras and transitions

Tags: java, android, xml, animation, transition

I'm trying to start a new activity that has this style:

```
<style name="SecondActivityStyle" parent="SomeParent">
        <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowEnterTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@transition/explode</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitTransition" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@transition/explode</item>
</style>
```

But the thing is, I was already sending a bundle with some Strings so I'm trying to create the bundle this way now:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    extras = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this).toBundle();
}

extras.putSerializable("user", user);
extras.putString("feedName", feedName);

final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(deepLink));
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But I'm always getting the default transition instead of the "explode" one. Could it be a problem with the extras in the bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, there is no problem with bundle. See the below answer to apply transition to activity programtically 
[How to achieve right to left animation to start the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26431017/how-to-achieve-right-to-left-animation-to-start-the-activity)